# error: instance member 'tomato' cannot be used on type 'hamburger'

Tags: swift, xcode

**1.what I code**

```
class hamburger {
var tomato: String
var patty: String
var bread: String
var number: Int
init(_ tomato: String, _ patty: String, _ bread: String, _ number: Int) {
    self.tomato = tomato
    self.patty = patty
    self.bread = bread
    self.number = number
}
init() {
    self.tomato = "tomato"
    self.patty = "patty"
    self.bread = "bread"
    self.number = 10
}
}   
let sandwich = hamburger("texas" , "iii" , "iii" , 10)
print(hamburger.tomato)
```

**2.error message**

```
Playground execution failed:

error: dotinstall.playground:342:7: error: instance member 'tomato' 
cannot be used on type 'hamburger'
print(hamburger.tomato)
  ^~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~
```

**3.The sample I followed**

```
enter code here// Class

class User {
let name: String // property
var score: Int
init(name: String, score: Int) {
init(_ name: String, _ score: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.score = score
}
init() {
    self.name = "bob"
    self.score = 30
 }
}

//let tom = User(name: "tom", score: 23)
let tom = User("tom", 23)
print(tom.name)
print(tom.score)

let bob = User()
print(bob.name)
print(bob.score)
```

I have coded like 1 following 3, but I got a error message like 2.

what I did to solve

・anyway follow this sample to be like same

・studied a basic of class syntax, initializer, instance on website

・was looking for a mistypes

・I checked the order of property

I don't why it is not worked even if I just follow the sample code.

please give me tips on the solution.

thanks

Comment: I would suggest to let the title of the question is to be more related to the issue instead of the typical error...

Comment: hamburger is your class name, not your new object. You meant `print(sandwich.tomato)`. BTW, class names should start with a capital letter by convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a mistake regarding object oriented programming. With `hamburger.tomato` you try to access the property tomato of the *Class* Hamburger, not the *Object*, which is sandwich here. So the solution would be:

```
print(sandwich.tomato)
```

In the future, what you might want to do is take a look at styling your code better. Classes(Hamburger) are written starting with an uppercased letter, while the objects, or instances(sandwich), of the Classes are written starting with a lowercased letter.